# I have difficulties using pivot_wider() with my R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to spread a dataframe using the function pivot_wider(). The data is the following,

```
    df <- structure(list(groupi = c("control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "experiment", 
"experiment", "experiment", "experiment", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control"), timing = c("post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre"), teacher = c("adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "ana", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", 
"nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "nick", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", 
"ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben", "ben"), item = c("Q1", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", 
"Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", 
"Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", 
"Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", 
"Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", 
"Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", 
"Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", 
"Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", 
"Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", 
"Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", 
"Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", 
"Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", 
"Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", 
"Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", 
"Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", 
"Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", 
"Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", 
"Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", 
"Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", 
"Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", 
"Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", 
"Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", 
"Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", 
"Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", 
"Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", 
"Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", 
"Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", 
"Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", 
"Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", 
"Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", 
"Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", 
"Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", 
"Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", 
"Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", 
"Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", 
"Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", 
"Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", 
"Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", 
"Q17", "Q18"), response = c(5, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 1, 6, 2, 4, 
5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5, 6, 2, 6, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 
3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2, 6, 4, 3, 
2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 
5, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 
6, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 
2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6, 
1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 3, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 
4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 2, 
2)), row.names = c(NA, -432L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

When I use the following code to have a column for "pre" and another for "post" from "timing",

```
df <- df %>% mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = timing, values_from = response)
```

I get a dataframe where all the scores in column "pre" has only NAs in the "post" column (and viceversa) because I am failing to code in a way that pivot_wider recognizes that in most of the cases the pre and post scores correspond to the same individual. The result that I want to obtain is to have scores in both ("pre" and "post"), but in the obvious cases where actually a "pre" score doesn't have the corresponding "post" (because individuals didn't take the post test, for example). I should mention that each student needed to respond each of the 18 questions at pre and post test. So, a given student "X" who is in the class of teacher "ben", responded 18 questions at the beginning of the semester and at the end of it. As you can see, the classes of teacher bob and nick were under the experiment and the classes of the rest of the teachers were control.

I have read many webpages and post here in Stack Overflow but I can't figure out the way to achieve this. How to achieve this?

Comment: R is no magic glass ball. How should it know which „pre“ value belongs to which „post“ value? If there is any logic (e.g. first pre value belongs to fiest post value), please let us know.

Comment: I suggest you write some code for determining the individuals IDs beforehand. `pivot_wider` can not "tell" which individual is which.

Comment: Adding that ID column makes all observations unique; that's why there's value in either *pre* or *post* but never in both.  When leaving ID column out, you should have a warning: "*Values from response are not uniquely identified*" and a snippet to check for duplicates ( `df %>% group_by(groupi, teacher, item, timing) %>% summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>% filter(n > 1L) `) Which in turn raises some concerns about the dataset:  there are no student IDs but the number of answers between pre and post of the same group is varying.

Comment: In other terms: what you need is a unique identifier for your  students.

Answer (score 0):

Variables *groupi*, *timing*, *teacher*, *item* have duplicated *response* values. Once the duplicated values are removed (or will be labeled) we get a reasonable result.

```
df[!duplicated(df[, -5]), ] %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(teacher, timing, groupi), 
    values_from=response, names_sort=T)
# A tibble: 18 × 11
   item  adam_…¹ adam_…² ana_p…³ ana_p…⁴ ben_p…⁵ ben_p…⁶ bob_p…⁷ bob_p…⁸ nick_…⁹
   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Q1          5       3       6       5       5       4       4       4       4
 2 Q2          4       6       6       6       5       6       4       5       3
 3 Q3          2       5       6       6       1       2       2       3       2
 4 Q4          3       5       6       6       3       5       4       4       5
 5 Q5          5       6       6       6       2       6       3       3       4
 6 Q6          3       6       6       6       1       5       2       4       3
 7 Q7          6       6       6       6       4       6       3       5       3
 8 Q8          1       1       1       6       4       6       5       1       2
 9 Q9          6       6       6       6       4       6       4       5       5
10 Q10         2       4       1       2       1       3       1       2       2
11 Q11         4       4       6       5       1       4       2       3       1
12 Q12         5       4       6       6       1       5       2       4       4
13 Q13         5       2       6       6       1       5       2       4       1
14 Q14         3       3       6       5       1       5       1       3       1
15 Q15         4       6       6       6       1       5       2       3       4
16 Q16         4       5       6       3       1       5       2       2       4
17 Q17         3       5       6       6       1       6       1       2       3
18 Q18         3       5       6       6       1       5       2       3       2
# … with 1 more variable: nick_pre_experiment <dbl>, and abbreviated variable
#   names ¹​adam_post_control, ²​adam_pre_control, ³​ana_post_control,
#   ⁴​ana_pre_control, ⁵​ben_post_control, ⁶​ben_pre_control,
#   ⁷​bob_post_experiment, ⁸​bob_pre_experiment, ⁹​nick_post_experiment
```

Comment: Since this looks like survey/experimental data, duplicates (in terms of identical answers) could bereasonably fine. Removing them would not be a solution in such a case.

Comment: @deschen Yes, keeping the values needs additional labels. Once added the approach should be similar though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. However, @AndreWildberg, How to include these additional labels?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but this is not what I am looking for. This issue has been an headache for me during 4 or 5 days.

Comment: @Marlom Can you add an expected result to your question via edit? That way one could directly judge whats missing or how to get the desired result.